# Can't remove pinned office applications

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-office, taskbar

My laptop is a Dell Precision 7510, running Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprice 64bit (10.0.15063 Build 15063) and Microsoft Office 365 ProPlus (1701 Build 7766.2092).

My problem is, that beside some useful apps on my taskbar, office has also pinned Word, Excel and PowerPoint. I would like to remove these 3 pinned apps. When unpinning them, they actually disappear, but after next restart (or restart of explorer.exe) they reaper as if nothing had happened.

I have tried following this "guide":
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/cant-unpin-a-program-from-the-taskbar/76e9bbc7-8717-4156-ab72-c9ac975dd6e9

I have seen the above suggestion posted on several sites, but unfortunately it doesn't help in my case.

When executing the script (or preforming the steps manually) all is removed, but after explorer.exe restart below icons always reaper:

- File Explorer
- Internet Explorer
- Outlook 2016
- PowerPoint 2016
- Word 2016
- Excel 2016

Other apps pinned at the time is removed as intended.

Does anyone have a suggestion to how I can remove these unwanted office apps from my taskbar? And why do above list or apps reapear after deleting them from both the %APPDATA% folder and REGEDIT?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try these options below:

**Clear all Unnecessary Startup programs**

Open Task Manager and go to Startup Tab and from there disallow any unnecessary programs to run at startup. Additionally also do check for viruses using some good anti-virus utility.

**Rebuild the Icon Cache**

Follow this guideline: [https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/5645-rebuild-icon-cache-windows-10-a.html](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/5645-rebuild-icon-cache-windows-10-a.html#option2)

**Clear and Reset the Thumbnail Cache**

Follow this guideline:[https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/5655-clear-reset-thumbnail-cache-windows-10-a.html](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/5655-clear-reset-thumbnail-cache-windows-10-a.html#option1)

**Create new User account**

If all of the above fails then you have no option without creating new user account. It is a guaranteed solution. It will not make any harm too. Only some of your files may get lost. So back them up before performing this step. Follow this article [here](https://www.top-password.com/blog/3-ways-to-create-new-administrator-account-in-windows-10/) to achieve this.

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Hello Rakibul Islam,

Comment: 1: Since my problem also occurs if you only restart explorer.exe (not the entire PC), I am pretty sure this will have no influence, unless my understanding off when startup programs are actually triggered.

2: As I can remove them in the first place, only for them to reappear, I don't quite follow the logic of why this should work, but I will try anyway and revert with results.

3: See above comment.

4: Unfortunately I can't. Users are controlled by the domain, to witch I am connected. Sorry if I didn't make this more clear in the original post.

Comment: Hi;

I have know tested your suggestions 1-3, without any change.

As previously stated, I can't create a new user, as they are controlled by the domain.

Comment: @HenrikNielsen I am feeling sorry for you but though it is hard to find the actual cause, most likely your User Profile is corrupted somehow....So, I guess you have no luck without contacting your domain administrator to provide you access to create a new user account.